# How can I get back code command in previous original vs code from vs code insiders?

Tags: vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

Actually I did and I got usefull. But now I want to go back to my previous vs code editor from the vscode insiders. But now if I use code. command in my vscode it is opening vscode insiders. How can I solve this problem?

Nothing I tried. I have no idea about the problem.

Comment: ... weird. I don't think that's supposed to happen. the command for VS Code Insiders should be `code-insiders`.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Copy the output from your VS Code, **and** your VS Code Insiders.